# Safari issue with @font-face in block element

Tags: css, safari, rendering, font-face

I have a @font-face I am using for a site. It renders fine in everything except Safari, and only in one instance there. The issue fixes itself when I remove display: block.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening & how to fix it?

The exact issue is that the font is rendering 'pixely'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Font was generated at font-squirrel. It works fine in Chrome (so not a general web-kit issue). And works fine everywhere the element isn't a 'display:block' element.

Comment: Can you provide a URL where we can see the problem? What does 'pixely' mean? Not anti-aliased?

Comment: Yes, not anti-aliased. I cannot give the url, it's in beta for a client, they would not be ok with me giving the url.

Comment: Can you provide a reduced test case then? It's difficult to help you with just the information in your question. Maybe this is the problem you are describing: http://getsatisfaction.com/typekit/topics/font_not_anti_aliasing_in_safari_4_0_4_on_os_x_10_6_2

Comment: I found the answer on that link - thanks so much Richard M! If you will do an answer I will choose it!

Comment: FYI - The error was fixed by adding opacity of .999 to a separate element in the same wrapper div. They shouldn't be related this way, but that was the fix. I found the fix thanks to Richard M at http://getsatisfaction.com/typekit/topics/font_not_anti_aliasing_in_safari_4_0_4_on_os_x_10_6_2

Answer (score -1):

Use Google web fonts API; it'll save you hours of time and it's designed for cross-browser compatibility.  @ http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html

Comment: How does this answer her question?

Comment: But they don't have the font I need & it the same font set up the same way works in other places & on other sites w/o the display: block

Comment: Modify your font sizes, see if that helps at all.  Do you have a pub link?

Comment: No reason to give minus one; it was an alternative solution, hence a possible answer...